# display UIView as an arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, transformation

I want to display a complex UI element as a kinda donut with sectors, so each sector could be represented as a single UIView.
Is there any way to transform the rectangular UIView into an arc to fit into donut contour? Or that's impossible?
I'm a total iOS noob and would be very appreciative if you pointed me to the right documentation.

Comment: Would it be ok to draw an Arc IN a rectangular UIView? That would be a easier.

Comment: not ok. i want to implement a new UI element that could be similar to UITableViewController, but instead a rectangular cells, there should be a way to insert any rectangular UIView descendant into arc-shaped cell.
with touch events, with rotations over the center

Comment: Sorry... not really following that?

Comment: I'm trying to make a UIView descendant with the UITableViewController behaviour. But. I want to display it as a donut with sectors and would like to place any UIView inside owner-drawn sector with help of some kind of transformations maybe, like UIViewAnimations

Comment: Well... that is VERY complicated control. You will have to look into standard Model / View programming style. You will need to implement a model that allows for the insertion of "donut" segment data objects with whatever properties you want them to have. Then you will have to manage BOTH touch events as well as screen display. The screen will still be drawn using CGLayer stuff in a rectangular space... kind of like what I suggested down below. Good luck and I sort of already answered the original question and pointed you in the direction of documentation you will need to consider.

Comment: My question is not how to draw a donut :) I want to know how to transform the UIView from rectangular shape into arc-shape

Answer (score 0):

`UIView`'s are always rectangular unless you apply an affine transform to it (but I still don't think you can get an arc shape). I think your best bet would be to draw the arc inside the UIView by subclassing the UIView and implementing `drawRect` or using `CAShapeLayer`.

Comment: yes, i want something like UIViewAnimation transformations to fit the rectangular UIView into owner-drawn arc sector of the donut view, is it real?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about exactly what your trying to do, I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest you use CGDrawing methods to draw your donut segments in a rectangular view.

To do that you would use the following in particular:

```
CGPathAddArc()
CGPathAddLineToPoint()
CGPathMoveToPoint()
```

This code draws filled arcs:

```
-(void)drawFilledArc:(CGContextRef)context innerRadius:(CGFloat)rIn outterRadius (CGFloat)rOut
    startAngle:(double)startAng endAngle:(double)endAng drawColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    float x1, y1;
    CGFloat centerX = originX;
    CGFloat centerY = originY;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);

    getChartWheelCoord(centerX, centerY, startAng, rIn, &x1, &y1);
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, x1, y1);

    getChartWheelCoord(centerX, centerY, startAng, rOut, &x1, &y1);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, x1, y1);

    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, centerX, centerY, rOut, radians(-startAng), radians(-endAng), YES);

    getChartWheelCoord(centerX, centerY, endAng, rIn, &x1, &y1);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, x1, y1);

    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, centerX, centerY, rIn, radians(-endAng), radians(-startAng), NO);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    CGPathRelease(path);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: did some clarifications in first comment

Answer (score 0):

Well You can achieve what you want in following ways.

1 If your UI Element has not to be answerable to Click or touch Events , then you can draw it
  Using Core-Graphics.

2 If your UI Element has to respond to user-interaction events then you can create a UIView
  and add as many custom-buttons as you want as subview to the UIview along with the arc   shaped or sector shaped images(Images for Custom Buttons).

Comment: How can i do the second one, but with any subviews (UIView descendants)?

Comment: could u send m d diagram with details.i could give u a sample program

Comment: well, i want something like this: http://f1.s.qip.ru/1q1ISx8F.png (not a designer, sorry for paint:)